# Window.opene does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-chrome

When I use window.open to open a window on ipad chrome,
I can't get window.opener and window.name.
But it works on mac chrome.

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.opener not set in iOS Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637937/window-opener-not-set-in-ios-chrome)